# Converting Python dictionary to List in which dict keys are at first index of the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have below List of dictionary,

```
[
    {
        "animal": "lion",
        "color": "yellow"
    },
    {
        "animal": "elephant",
        "color": "black" 
    }
]
```

I needed output as list of list in below format,

```
[
    ["animal","color"],
    ["lion","yellow"],
    ["elephant","black"]
]
```

Comment: May I know why I get downvote ?

Comment: For what purpose? There are already modules that handle specific cases.

Comment: @RajagopalSubramanian welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Actually I want to use this type of structure in front end graph. See https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart.  Please see the data structure they used to populate the graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, extract the keys from the first dictionary in your list. Then, construct lists by applying these keys to each dictionary.

```
keys = sorted(list_of_dicts[0].keys())
table = [keys] + [[d[k] for k in keys] for d in list_of_dicts]
# [['animal', 'color'], ['lion', 'yellow'], ['elephant', 'black']]
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried without sorted() it returns `[dict_keys(['animal','color']) , ['lion','yellow']]`.  May I know why ?

Comment: @RajagopalSubramanian In Python 3.X, `dict.keys` will return a `dict_keys` object. You could explicitly convert it to a `list` if you don't care about the order of the keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import itertools
l = [
 {
   "animal": "lion",
    "color": "yellow"
 },
 {
    "animal": "elephant",
    "color": "black"
 }
]

headers = list(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable([i.keys() for i in l])))

headers.extend([i.values() for i in l])
print(headers)
```

Output:

```
[['animal', 'color'], ['lion', 'yellow'], ['elephant', 'black']]
```

Comment: @RajagopalSubramanian could you elaborate? Do you mean n number of headers?

Comment: yes. Also in`first = header[1][0]` I got `TypeError: 'dict_items' object does not support indexing`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ajax1234.